# Selecting parent and parent's sibings in a single jquery/javascript statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is this jquery/javascript statement correct and valid.

```js
$('.icon_edit').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide().siblings('span').hide();
});
```

```html
<div class="dataBox">
 <span>
  <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox"/>
 </span>
 <span class="memName">test1</span>
 <span class="memNum">9791091380</span>
 <span class="memDesc">test 1</span>
 <span>
  <a class="icon-delete" >&nbsp;</a>
  <a class="icon-edit" >&nbsp;</a>
 </span>
 <div>
  <input class="editName"/>
  <input class="editNum"/>
  <input class="editDesc"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

I was actually trying to hide the selected elements parent + all the siblings of the parent which are 'span' element in a single statement. Is there a better way to do this.?
NB:Actually this code is working for me. But not sure if its violating any syntax or selection rules of javascript/jquery.This is how I did it in 2 statements

```js
$(this).parent().hide().siblings('span').hide();
$(this).parent().hide();
```

Comment: This should be moved to [codereview.se]. Add the HTML markup.

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().hide().end().siblings('span').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative approach,

```
$(this).parent().siblings('span').andSelf().hide();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/107/)

Comment: `.andSelf` will select the `<a>`  or its parent `<span>`??

Comment: thanks man. that did really worked..